# How to determine current keyboard language in C++ console application?

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard

Need c++ function from windows.h that returns current keyboard language for the active window.

Comment: There is `GetConsoleCP` (and yes, I realize a code page isn't the same as the language -- but AFAIK, it's about all you can do that applies directly to a console).

Comment: I tried but it still returns the same code for different languages(

Answer (score 1):

Try using GetKeyboardLayout function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646296(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This function returns some value that remains the same after changing keyboard language. Are there some other variants?

Comment: In constantly returns english language.

Comment: For console applications, it seems that one must use GetKeyboardLayout for a parent GUI process, e.g. `conhost.exe` in Windows 7. See the last comment in this discussion: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/43043-get-current-keyboard-layout/

Comment: Thank you. This man proposes to include his dll into the project, but unfortunately I need to do this without external libraries if it is possible.